# Getting error in cout Simple code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I'm wondering why I'm getting an error.
The error is: `cout is undefined`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main()
{
    cout<<"Why am I not working ??";
    printf("My Name is Khan and I'm not a terrorist.");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout` is in the `std` namespace. You either need to declare that you are using the `std` namespace by adding the following to your code (it is generally put just after includes), though this is [generally considered bad practise for non-trivial code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice):

```
using namespace std;
```

Or you can qualify `cout` every time it is used (this is generally preferred):

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: You don't really *need* to declare that you are using the `std` namespace. It is not necessary to present it as an option, even if you do warn it is a bad one. There's also `using std::cout`.

Answer (score 3):

`cout` is a global object that lives in the `std` namespace. You have to fully qualify the name:

```
    std::cout << "Hello";
//  ^^^^^
```

If you really want to omit the qualification, you could have a `using` declaration in `main()` before you use the unqualified name `cout` (in general, avoid putting `using` declarations at global namespace scope):

```
// ...

int main() 
{
    using std::cout;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    cout << "Why I'm not working ??";
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you don't even mention the wrong "solution" :)

Comment: @H2CO3: I had to think a bit of how to mention it in a non-wrong way :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following before `int main`:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Anyone care to qualify their down-vote?  My suggestion *will* solve the OP's problem.  And given the way they wrote the code in their example, this is the **the** solution they wanted... as opposed to the std::cout solution.

Comment: It is generally a bad solution. And a better solution would even involve less typing.

Comment: @juanchopanza Do we just take your word for it that this solution is "bad"?  Also, depending on how many occurrences of "cout" the code has, the std::cout solution requires more typing.

Comment: +1: using namespace directives are not a bad thing in source files. They are definitely bad in header files, since they get included and pollute other code.

Comment: No, there are plenty of posts about this on SO.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I have seen many, many problems die to placing `using namespace std` in `.cpp` files. If you're going to do that, at least put it in a scope.